# C++ in ubuntu(linux platforms)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I want to start developing c++ programs in the linux platforms. So can anyone tell me where to start learning c++ for linux, the compiler, etc.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do a quick

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and you will have a C++ compiler which you invoke with `g++`.

As for learning resources, there are vast amounts of information for C++ programming. Your best bet is to google for phrases like "linux c++ programming".

Don't forget to check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), which is the definitive C++ book guide.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu. I currently use Code:Blocks for my IDE (in the Universe repository) and Visual Paradigm Home Edition for my design/development software (it's not in the repository but is free). You will need build-essential to use Code:Blocks, as the other poster suggested. I also like gdb for the purpose of figuring out where a segfault happens and the like.